# Create end credits for video editing

Tags: video-editor, pitivi

I am using Pitivi for some video editing and now I want to add end credits to the end of video. I don't know if it's possible to do it directly in Pitivi (if so how?).

[Here](https://developer.pitivi.org/GSoC_Ideas.html?gi-language=undefined) it gives some hint but no clear explanation. So I am wondering if there is any external tool to create scrolling end credits video in Ubuntu and then add it directly to the video editor?

Answer (score 0):

- Create a large image with the credits to be scrolled
- Add the image as a clip
- Click the clip to select it
- In the Clip tab in the middle pane, click the rhombus button at the bottom of the Transformation section to "keyframe" the position of the clip (x/y/w/h)
- Use Ctrl+Left and Ctrl+Right to seek to the start of the clip
- Place the image at the position where the scrolling starts.
- Use Ctrl+Left and Ctrl+Right to seek to the end of the clip
- Place the image at the end scrolling position.

The placement can be controlled by manually entering the x/y/w/h values, by using the `#` widget on the right side, or by dragging the image in the viewer.

If you need to change the length of the clip you'll have to click the rightmost button called "Reset to default values" and repeat.

You can create multiple position keyframes by moving the playhead (seeking) and then dragging the image in the viewer. This way you can vary the scroll speed (no acceleration though) and make it move towards multiple positions. Have fun!

Comment: what are ctrl+L and ctrl+R supposed to do? it seems nothing hapens